# How to monitor 20+ xubuntu computers with vnc

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, monitoring

So I'm trying to setup a classroom network that allows all the kids to access the server using xubuntu as a thin client. I have the whole thing setup, however I now need to view all of them on a single computer running Ubuntu 16.04 so I can monitor classroom activity and help with certain assignments if need be. I can't find anything that would do this for me, so I'm thinking that i could run all of them throught vnc or rdp on a single computer. Is there any software or suggestions that anyone can think of to let me view 20+ computers? If I have to separate the viewing to more computers I can.

Comment: I think VNC will not be practical. Maybe xrdp ? But really, you are looking for a specialized tool for classrooms : **VEYON** is a FOSS for Linux/Windows, maybe that's something to try. There is also **Mythware** and [iTALC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22461/supervisory-software-for-school-rooms) was the answer to this question on Unix StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Epoptes](http://www.epoptes.org/).

[image: Epoptes is action]

It usually works together with [LTSP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP), but you can try to setup it for you needs, I hope.

Epoptes scalability is great, I monitored >40 machines with it.