# How to control multiple computers from one?

Tags: server, ssh, remote, cluster

Once I saw a friend who had created a study room where there were 10 PCs running Ubuntu. From each one of the PCs you could login into your personal account. There was also an 11th PC which was was called the admin PC (If i recall correctly it was supposed to be on all the time while the others not). From this admin pc he could create new user accounts for new students for example and monitor what they where doing if needed.

[image]

I am trying to replicated this set up as well but I cannot find information about it. Do you have any suggestion where I could start from in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: This question is too broad and I suggest doing more research.  There are multiple ways to do this and it involves a lot more than just one task. Ex. Setting up and administering a network, installing monitoring/surveillance software.  You could answer this question with a book or teach a class about it, so your question is not suited for our Q&A format and is off-topic.  If you have a specific narrowly-focused issue you need help with you can ask practical answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monitor 20+ xubuntu computers with vnc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004763/how-to-monitor-20-xubuntu-computers-with-vnc) The actual possible solution is to use LTSP with Epoptes and GoSA2.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for your comment! Well this is not exactly how I was imagining it. I was looking for something so that when you boot up the user's PC you have the option to log in to an account.

Comment: Epoptes allows assistance mode: admin can use controls on users computer.

Comment: @N0rbert This is very interesting and point to the direction of what I am trying to do. I think I need to study also LSTP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monitor 20+ xubuntu computers with vnc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004763/how-to-monitor-20-xubuntu-computers-with-vnc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the right answer to my question. What is needed is called Linux Terminal Server Project (LTSP).
Here there is a guide on how to practically achieve the task:
https://wiki.debian.org/LTSP

Comment: This can be done on Ubuntu too. But the most integrated solution is Debian Edu (Skolelinux) - see https://blends.debian.org/edu/ .